# Misunderstanding rollback in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

I not familiar with mysql but i just think about trouble if i using START TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK for 2 client or more then i have a error in one time, for example:

```
AT ONE TIME
Client 1:
START TRANSACTION -> insert query 1 -> insert query 2 - insert query 3
Client 2:
START TRANSACTION -> insert Query 4 -> error and rollback
```

if client 2 rollback (i just think) query 4 rollback and query 1 too, correct (I just assumed)?
i can't checkout that, how we can check this?

**UPDATE :**

IF that SITUATION:

```
AT ONE TIME, ID is PRIMARY (ai)
Client 1:
START TRANSACTION -> insert tbl1 (ID : 1) -> error and rollback
Client 2:
START TRANSACTION -> insert tbl1 (ID : 2) -> insert tbl2 (ID : 2)
```

(i just think) this transaction from client 1 is Pasted and ID 1 if lost? and other transaction continue using id 3,4,5 etc..., true or not?

Comment: Transactions and commit / rollback are per client / connection. A rollback on client 2 wouldn't do anything to client 1's transaction. The amount of chaos that would cause if it wasn't that way...

Comment: check my update @JonStirling

Comment: Ah, yes I believe in that case ID 1 would be lost, the second would still be ID 2 and auto-increment would continue from there. Though my information may be outdated.

Comment: Do you have a solution? @JonStirling you have point from stackoverflow too many .... you'r advanced! please give me solution...

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of solution you want, that's how it's expected to work.